# Creating a Follower following model in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, twitter-follow

[image: Trying to get my head around a following-follower model in Core Data]

Hi I'm trying to create a follower-following model (like Twitter) in Core Data. Maybe I'm too used to using IDs, I'm not sure if this correct. If possible, can someone please give me some advice.

Thanks

Comment: OK, you have posted a diagram of a core data model, and a tiny bit of text, but... what, exactly, is your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need only the "BDOUser" entity and a "many-to-many" relationship from "BDOUser" to itself.

- Define "followers" as to-many relationship from "BDOUser" to "BDOUser".
- Define "followings" as to-many relationship from "BDOUser" to "BDOUser".
- Set "followings" as inverse relationship to "followers".

Now you can do things like

```
[userA addFollowersObject:userB];
```

That will

- add "userB" to the followers of "userA", and automatically also
- add "userA" to the followings of "userB".

Comment: what if you need to track things like followed_at, would probably need a join right?

Comment: @martin  what if you want to remove follower userB from followers of userA ?
How would be a good unfollow?

Comment: @Florentt: Something like `[userA removeFollowersObject:userB];`

Comment: @martin thanks bro i did that before didnt work didnt remove the connection but i probably forgot something and its working now, thanks for the tip bro.